# Insert or Update with prepared statements in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

Trying to make insert or update sql using the prepared statements from php's pdo. First I thought of using `REPLACE INTO` command,but it gives me an error because I have a foreign key on my index. Read that I must use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax to make it working, but it's not clear for me how to do that with prepared statements. Any solution for this? Thanks.

The sql is :

```
$sql="REPLACE INTO fn_currencies(id,short,name,buy,sell,date) VALUES (:id,:short,:name,:buy,:sell,:update)";
```

**UPD:** I am making this query in Yii that uses personal wrapper over the PDO.
When I use unnamed parameters I get this type of error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `fn_currencies` (id,short,name,buy,sell,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=?,short=?,name=?,buy=?,sell=?,date=?
```

When I use the named parameters with differed names for Insert and Update as was mentioned..I get no errors and neither data is inserted in my DB.
Here is the schema for the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fn_currencies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `short` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `buy` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
  `sell` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
ALTER TABLE `fn_currencies`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_fn_currencies` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `fn_operations` (`currency_id`);
```

Comment: The thing that I suspect is getting you confused is that you cannot use a named parameter in a prepared statement more than once. This means that you will have to write it a e.g. `INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES (:field1i, :field2i) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = :field1u, field2 = :field2u` and you will have to duplicate the data you send. It slightly sucks programmatically but it does work (just tested it)

Comment: @DaveRandom Huh? Reusing named parameters works just fine, unless my memory is failing me really badly.

Comment: @deceze [`You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement.`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: It doesn't gives the errors but after execution there are no values in the DB.. what can be that?

Comment: @Dave I'm pretty sure I've written code like `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (:baz) ON DUPLICATE UPDATE bar = :baz` before and it worked. That statement may be wrong or mean something else.

Comment: @deceze I've just been trying it and it does in fact seem to work (in 5.4.3 at least). It looks like (surprise surprise) the manual is wrong. Silly me, assuming the documented behaviour is the actual behaviour. Having said that, I'm sure I once tried it and it failed. Still, I stand at least partially if not wholly corrected.

Comment: @VitKos Can you show you current code an DB schema? Have you inspected [`PDO::errorInfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) for error messages?

Comment: wait a  sec will update the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to DavaRandom, he pointed out an error in my code, but this should do the trick. Replace the named parameter with `?` and use an array merge to make the SQL on the fly like this:

```
$sql="
    insert INTO fn_currencies(id,short,name,buy,sell,date) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
    on duplicate key update currencies set 
        short=?, name=?, buy=?, sell=?, update=?";
$values=array("id"=>1, "short"=>36, "name"=>'Bazinga', "sell"=>3.67, "date"=>'2012-08-08');
$db->query($sql, array_merge(array_values($values),array_values($values)));
```

Apparently this will also work (See comments all over the page about yes/no/maybe) but the above will certainly work:

```
$sql="
    insert INTO fn_currencies(id,short,name,buy,sell,date) 
    VALUES (:id,:short,:name,:buy,:sell,:update)
    on duplicate key update currencies set 
        short=:short, name=:name, buy=:buy, sell=:Sell, update=:update";
```

Comment: You can't use named parameters more than once in the same query. Which does suck a bit, I admit. Also you don't need the table name or the `SET` keyword in the `UPDATE` section.

Comment: @DaveRandom Hey, thanks for that, but how about these apples?

Comment: Looks good - although if you look through the comments on the Q you'll see that I have been corrected on the reuse of named parameters point. Stupidly, I believed what I read in the manual. But either way, using un-named parameters guarantees it will work.

Comment: @DaveRandom *facepalm*, so my answer was right the first time? Ahh well, at least I know of a sure-fire way to make it work :)

Comment: @VitKos Are you absolutely sure that none of your parameters are empty? If you are using the `$values=array(...)` method I suggested, can you do a `print_r($values)` just prior to the SQL execution?